# Datagridview checkbox error in commit edit in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

This is the code that I use in my button to commit the edit in the datagridview:

```
dgv.CommitEdit(True)
```

When I check a checkbox in the datagridview, and press the button with the code above, it gives this error:

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

this error come from Auto Generate Designer Code.
Sometimes, visual studio generate True or False value option for checkbox with empty string.

> ```
>     Me.fCheck.DataPropertyName = "fCheck"
>     Me.fCheck.FalseValue = ""
>     Me.fCheck.HeaderText = "เลือก"
>     Me.fCheck.Name = "fCheck"
>     Me.fCheck.TrueValue = ""
>     Me.fCheck.Width = 40
> ```

You have to delete them or change empty string value to True or False value instead.

> ```
>     Me.fCheck.DataPropertyName = "fCheck"
>     Me.fCheck.FalseValue = False
>     Me.fCheck.HeaderText = "เลือก"
>     Me.fCheck.Name = "fCheck"
>     Me.fCheck.TrueValue = True
>     Me.fCheck.Width = 40
> ```